# JQuery select the class needed

Tags: jquery

I am lookign to select the otf_itm class but I have it used twice in this particular page. I need to use the label as the root for selecting the otf_itm. I have used the following and works ok but I want to check and make sure if it is the best practise to use in this situation.

JS:

```
$("label[for='town_id']").next().children();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label for="town_id">Town:</label>
    <div class="col-md-3 controls">

        <div class="otf_itm">
            <!-- form items that chagne due to other data -->
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `$("label[for='town_id']").next().find('.otf_itm')` would work well. `.next()` would be good if the structure does not change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use like this

```
$("label[for='town_id']").next().find(".otf_itm");
```

`find()` will search for the child elements in any levels. While `children()` will search for the first level child elements.

In your case, both `find()` and `children()` will work fine.

Or you can use like this too,

```
$("label[for='town_id']").closest(".form-group").find(".otf_itm");
```

`closest()` will get the parent with specified class